# writing to /proc/irq/*/smp_affinity as root

Tags: proc

Here is the command I issued:

```
root@vishal-Think:~# echo "0" > /proc/irq/0/smp_affinity
```

And here is the error:

```
-bash: echo: write error: Input/output error
```

The ls command shows that root has write permissions:

```
root@vishal-Think:~# ls -l /proc/irq/0/smp_affinity
-rw------- 1 root root 0 May 21 16:30 /proc/irq/0/smp_affinity
```

Please tell me how I could fix this.

Another question of mine is that even after disabling irqbalance and rebooting the machine, I still see interrupts going to cpus other than cpu0. Why could that be happening?

Answer (score 0):

IRQ 0 is timer interrupt and is handled only by core 0. This can not be moved to other cores.

Answer (score -1):

/proc is a virtual file system and although the information appears to be a file, you do not write to the files.

See http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html

I am not sure what the problem is with your hardware or how to fix it. Please update your question describing the problem and what you did to generate that error message.

Comment: As shown in my post, I tried to echo into /proc/irq0/smp_affinity. Is that not the correct method? If not, then how do I change the interrupt affinity in Ubuntu.

Comment: That is a very broad question and I would refer you to the linux kerenl documentation. On this site, I suggest you identify your hardware and describe the problem. What makes you think you need to change the interrupt affinity?

Comment: normally the echo as root should work temporarily. Obviously you have a problem, hard to know the best solution, may well be to file a bug report against the linux kernel.